# How to enter text with ' into table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following text:

```
Price is .....

return policy is....

Mega's accept....
```

I want to insert this whole text into a column of type `TEXT`

What I wrote was:

```
Insert into A (id,msg) values (5, '    Price is .....

    return policy is....

    Mega's store online ....')
```

`Mega's` is the name of the store. The `'` in this name causes the query to think that it's the end of the text...

So I get the error message:

> ERROR: column "Price is ....." does not exist

I tried to Insert with SELECT, but that doesn't work either. I get the same error message.

How do I perform this insert?

Comment: How are you creating/running the INSERT statement? Is this in a query window or from an application that you've written?

Comment: Whether or not you think that SQL injection is an issue, there's no reason NOT to avoid it, especially given how easy it is to code against it.

Comment: Considering how easy it is to use [prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), there's really no reason not to use them.  I'd use it just to not have to worry about escaping characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to (or can't) change the actual text, use [dollar quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING). Just replace the first and last `'` with e.g. `$$`:

```
Insert into A (id,msg) values (5, $$    Price is .....
    return policy is....
    Mega's store online ....$$)
```

You need to use a delimiter that does not occur in the actual text. If your text *can* contain `$$` you can use something different, e.g: `$not_there$`

```
Insert into A (id,msg) values (5, $not_there$    Price is .....
    return policy is....
    Mega's store online ....$not_there$)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just double the single quote inside the string: `'Mega''s store online'`.

Alternatively, you can pass any string through the function `quote_literal()` and that will then take care of proper quoting and other issues such as [SQL-injection](http://bobby-tables.com). That is useful when the string comes from some application that allows single quotes in a string.

The `INSERT` command should be:

```
Insert into A (id,msg) values (5, '    Price is .....'
'return policy is....'
'Mega''s store online ....');
```

You can break a long string over multiple lines, but every lines has to have an opening and closing single quote.

Comment: Is there something that I can do without actualy reading the text? I read that it's possible to use $ instad of ' but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CHAR(39).

Example:

```
Mega' + CHAR(39) + 's store online....'
```

For reference: http://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php

Comment: My apologies - didnt notice your postgres tag.  Dollar signs should be your answer